# Adding [httpclient] to new questions should be blocked

Tags: discussion, tags, blocklist-request

[httpclient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpclient) has description:

> DO NOT USE - Use [apache-commons-httpclient], [apache-httpclient-4.x]
>   or [dotnet-httpclient]

but is still [frequently added to more and more new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/httpclient?sort=newest&pageSize=30).

Comment: According to the [meta-tag:blacklist-request] tag info, blacklisting a tag also removes the tag from existing posts. So it needs to be cleaned up before blacklisting can be considered.

Comment: I agree with @Stijn that this needs to be cleaned up before it can be blocked. Unfortunately, having three different tags that we need to disambiguate makes this awkward to create a synonym for.

Comment: I can't see, why would it be unclear. Click the tag - it is still used on more than 4000 questions.