# What should we do with [iphone6] and [iphone6+]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

The pattern of iPhone version tags has been [iphone-3gs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-3gs), [iphone-4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-4) and [iphone-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-5).

Should these new tags also use the hyphen? A less important observation is that the phone is called iPhone "6 Plus," not "6+".

Comment: Agreed on both points.

Comment: Is [iphone-\d] even useful? I mean... aren't all of them [ios]?

Comment: @Braiam No; the [tag:iphone] tag is used for questions dependent on hardware. The version extensions of that tag are used just as you would use versioning for other tags, like [tag:html].

Comment: @AstroCB but, is it useful? Does anyone cares what iphone you are using? Python guys say "no".

Comment: @Braiam It matters in cases where you're discussing screen sizes or version-specific hardware issues.

Comment: @AstroCB and, as I said in chat, is that even relevant from the entirely developer point of view what the hardware does or does not? They just have to use the API/ABI that Apple provides through the OS, iOS. The fact that it doesn't work as *it is documented* is never HW relevant. Is just a documentation bug.

Comment: @Braiam Fair point; let's see what others have to say.

Comment: Sometimes it matters what iPhone you are using: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25755443/iphone-6-plus-resolution-confusion-xcode-or-apples-website

Comment: @Braiam for example for a hardware-dependent feature (such as a game that needs to change its graphics to run smoothly on older, less powerful devices) or if a bug only happens on a particular device it's nice to have tags for them.

Comment: @AndréDaniel but are they working actually like that? Or are just "Imma using iPhone 6 dunno wat tis wrong?" kind of thing?

Comment: @Braiam wouldn't a tag wiki "for hardware-dependent issues only, for general iPhone development questions use the [ios] tag" solve that issue ?

Comment: @AndréDaniel in a pink colored world, sure, it should, in reality, [not](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267130/792066) [so](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268141/792066) [much.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/apple). Also read Bolt's answer.

Comment: @Braiam if someone can't even understand a tag wiki then his questions has probably other major issues and will be closed anyway, so no big deal. I'd say just wait and see, eventually once the iPhone 6 is released we may need to do something if the tag is indeed massively misused but for right now I don't think any action is needed.

Comment: @Braiam Take it from a sometime iPhone developer, yes, it's relevant. Look at the top-voted questions for [tag:iphone-4] and [tag:iphone-5] -- they're all about screen resolution issues specific to those devices. With two new devices each with a new and different screen resolution, those sorts of questions are going to come out of the woodwork.

Comment: @Braiam [FYI, we've had a variant of this discussion before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260593/making-iphone-ipod-touch-and-ipad-tags-synonyms-of-the-inclusive-ios). Long story short, there are solid reason for having an iPhone and iPad tag, though we didn't discuss having tags for each version of the iDevices.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I renamed [iphone6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone6) to [iphone-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6) and created a synonym for [iphone6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone6%2b) to [iphone-6-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6-plus).

Honestly, if people can't even be bothered to get these little things right, then I wouldn't want their apps on my iPhone. They should just go develop for Android or something.

Comment: ༼ ͒ ̶ ͒༽ <- if ever I wanted a unicode troll face it is now...

Comment: Ouch.  Don't send them over to Android.  I hear that the Windows phone needs a community...

Comment: You are a bit too late, @Makoto. Have you looked at the [tag:android] tag recently? It is a constant source of problems.

Comment: Gotdamnit @Makoto keep your crap devs away from my phone!

Comment: In my experience, 99% of the apps on any platform are rubbish.

Comment: [90% of everything is crap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sturgeon%27s_law)

Comment: @Noelkd Its a wonder what I just learned at this time in the morning !

Answer (score 4):

Only one question was tagged [iphone6+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone6%2b), so I burninated that tag (obviously the person who created it didn't check the existing formats or bother with the device's proper name) and replaced it with [iphone-6-plus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6-plus) to use the existing naming scheme.

There are currently 7 questions tagged [iphone6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone6), so hopefully a moderator can step in and replace it with [iphone-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6), because regular users cannot create the [iphone-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone-6) tag due to its similarity to [iphone6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/iphone6). The [question that created the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751369/support-iphone-6-screen-resolution-along-with-other-resolutions-universally) is currently closed.

Comment: Perhaps burnination is the wrong approach here. That tag is likely to get recreated. It is unfortunate that all the community can do on their own is burninate, rather than create synonyms.

Comment: @CodyGray True; I probably would have suggested a synonym if I had a score of 5+ on the tag, which currently only one user has.